# How do the compact Hausdorff topologies sit in the lattice of all topologies on a set?

Tags: set-theory, gn.general-topology, lattice-theory, hausdorff-spaces

This question is about the space of all topologies on a
fixed set X. We may order the topologies by refinement, so
that τ ≤ σ just in case every τ open set is open in σ.
Equivalently, we say in this case that τ is *coarser*
than σ, that σ is *finer* than τ or that
σ *refines* τ. (See [wikipedia on comparison of
topologies](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_topologies).)
The least element in this order is the indiscrete topology and the largest topology is the discrete topology.

One can show that the collection of all topologies on a fixed set is a complete lattice. In the downward direction, for example, the intersection of any collection of
topologies on X remains a topology on X, and this intersection
is the largest topology contained in them all. Similarly,
the union of any number of topologies generates a smallest
topology containing all of them (by closing under finite
intersections and arbitrary unions). Thus, the collection of all topologies on X is a complete
lattice.

Note that the compact topologies are closed downward in
this lattice, since if a topology τ has fewer open sets than
σ and σ is compact, then τ is compact.
Similarly, the Hausdorff topologies are closed upward,
since if τ is Hausdorff and contained in σ, then
σ is Hausdorff. Thus, the compact topologies inhabit
the bottom of the lattice and the Hausdorff topologies the
top.

These two collections kiss each other in the compact
Hausdorff topologies. Furthermore, these kissing points,
the compact Hausdorff topologies, form an antichain in the
lattice: no two of them are comparable. To see this,
suppose that τ subset σ are both compact
Hausdorff. If U is open with respect to σ, then the
complement C = X - U is closed with respect to σ and
hence compact with respect to σ in the subspace
topology. Thus C is also compact with respect to τ in
the subspace topology. Since τ is Hausdorff, this
implies (an elementary exercise) that C is closed with respect to τ, and so U is
in τ. So τ = σ. Thus, no two distinct compact Hausdorff topologies are comparable, and so these topologies are spread out sideways, forming an antichain of the lattice.

My first question is, do the compact Hausdorff topologies
form a maximal antichain? Equivalently, is every topology
comparable with a compact Hausdorff topology? [Edit:  François points out an easy counterexample in the comments below.]

A weaker version of the question asks merely whether every
compact topology is refined by a compact Hausdorff
topology, and similarly, whether every Hausdorff topology
refines a compact Hausdorff topology. Under what
circumstances is a compact topology refined by a unique
compact Hausdorff topology? Under what circumstances does a
Hausdorff topology refine a unique compact Hausdorff
topology?

What other topological features besides compactness and
Hausdorffness have illuminating interaction with this
lattice?

Finally, what kind of lattice properties does the lattice
of topologies exhibit? For example, the lattice has atoms,
since we can form the almost-indiscrete topology having
just one nontrivial open set (and any nontrivial subset
will do). It follows that every topology is the least upper
bound of the atoms below it. The [lattice of topologies is
complemented](http://www.smc.math.ca/cjm/v20/cjm1968v20.0805-0807.pdf).
But the lattice is not distributive (when X has at least
two points), since it embeds N<sub>5</sub> by the
topologies involving {x}, {y} and the topology generated by
{{x},{x,y}}.

Comment: The maximal antichain question has a negative answer for infinite X. Split X into two infinite halves put the discrete topology on one half and the indiscrete topology on the other.

Comment: Yes, of course you are right, Francois; the first question is too easy. Please proceed to answer the rest of my questions so beautifully!

Comment: You probably already know this, but Terence Tao wrote a nice post on the "compact/Hausdorff duality" here: http://terrytao.wordpress.com/2009/02/09/245b-notes-10-compactness-in-topological-spaces/

Comment: Is it obvious that there exists a compact Hausdorff topology on every set?

Comment: @Qiaochu: The order topology on a successor ordinal is compact Hausdorff.

Comment: *Is it obvious that there exists a compact Hausdorff topology on every set?* Yes (using the well-ordering theorem) ... the order topology on the set of ordinals up to and including a given ordinal.

Comment: *every compact topology is refined by a compact Hausdorff topology* No, there exist maximal compact topologies that are not Hausdorff and vice versa.  Look for "maximal compact" in the title of the paper...

Comment: Steen & Seebach 99.


Comment: For those who don't have the book, Steen & Seebach #99 is on Google books:

http://books.google.com/books?id=DkEuGkOtSrUC&lpg=PA118&ots=3hHBTJE-k7&dq=maximal%20compact%20topology&pg=PA118#v=onepage&q=maximal%20compact%20topology&f=false

Comment: Steen & Seebach 100 (Minimal Hausdorff Topology) answers the other question.

Comment: About Qiaochu's question: is it conceivable that it is a weak AC principle that every set has a compact Hausdorff topology?

Comment: The questions about uniqueness are not yet answered, and neither are the questions about other lattice features.

Comment: Also, the question about maximal compact but non-Hausdorff topologies and minimal Hausdorff but incompact topologies appears to still be unsettled when the underlying space is uncountable.

Comment: @Joel ... I'm not sure I understand this.  Why not split off a countable subset, do your example there, and put a compact Hausdorff topology on the rest?

Comment: Another strange comment... without AC, you have to say what you mean by "compact" ... and if you choose something about finite subcovers you have to say what you mean by "finite".


Comment: Gerald, you are completely right about the uncountable case. About AC, I think everyone would want to define compact via the finite subcover definition, even if we lose the equivalence with other formulations. Finally, I don't think that "finite" loses its meaning if AC fails.  A set is finite if it is bijective with a natural number, and without AC this can be different from being Dedekind finite (not being bijective with any proper subset), but I believe most people are careful to distinguish these notions.

Comment: About Qiaochu's question: >> Is it obvious that there exists a compact Hausdorff topology on every set? << Let $X\neq \emptyset$ be a set, fix $x_0\in X$. Let $\tau = \mathcal{P}(X\setminus\{x_0\}) \cup \{U\subseteq X : X\setminus U \textrm{ is finite }\}$. Then $\tau$ is a compact Hausdorff topology on $X$.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan For any nonempty set $X$, pick an element $x$ and topologize $X$ as a one-point compactification of the discrete space $X \backslash \{x\}$ (I think this is what dominiczypen was trying to say).

Answer (score 40, accepted):

**This is a community wiki of the answers in the comments.**

- The compact Hausdorff topologies do not generally form a maximal antichain. If X is infinite, split X into two infinite halves and put the discrete topology on one half and the indiscrete topology on the other half. (Comment by François G. Dorais) **Addendum:** Without sufficient Choice, the infinite set $X$ may be [amorphous](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amorphous_set). Amorphous sets are *precisely* the infinite sets for which this approach doesn't work. Very little Choice is needed to ensure that no such beast exists. (Edit by Cameron Buie)
- There is a maximal compact topology on a countable space which is not  Hausdorff. See [Steen & Seebach 99](http://books.google.com/books?id=DkEuGkOtSrUC&lpg=PA118&ots=3hHBTJE-k7&dq=maximal%20compact%20topology&pg=PA118#v=onepage&q=&f=false). (Comment by Gerald Edgar)
- There is a minimal Hausdorff topology on a countable space which is not compact. See [Steen & Seebach 100](http://books.google.com/books?id=DkEuGkOtSrUC&lpg=PA118&ots=3hHBTJE-k7&dq=maximal%20compact%20topology&pg=PA119#v=onepage&q=&f=false). (Comment by François G. Dorais)
- Those examples can be lifted to any cardinality space, simply by using the disjoint sum with any given compact Hausdorff space. (Comment by Gerald Edgar)
- Every set admits a compact Hausdorff topology, by topologizing it as the one-point compactification of the discrete space structure on the complement of any point. (Answer below by Cameron Buie)

(*Feel free to edit and expand*)

Comment: Great! This is exactly the sort of answer for which I was hoping (although I don't like the restriction to countable spaces---I wonder if it can be generalized?). Thanks François, Gerald and Qiaochu for the great information (and especially Gerald for the Steen and Seebach reference). But now I observe that since you all answered in comments, we are unable to bestow the deserved reputation on any of you....

Comment: For purposes of bestowing reputation, ask only one question per post.  You are more likely to get answers rather than comments.

Answer (score 16):

I see that I'm rather late to the party. Here's an answer to the following question that you asked in the comments above:

> "[I]s it conceivable that it is a weak AC principle that every set has a compact Hausdorff topology?"

In fact, there is no need for any choice principle at all, if by *finite*, we mean in bijection with a natural number (or something equivalent), not Dedekind-finite. Obviously, the empty set's only topology is compact Hausdorff.

Suppose $X$ is a non-empty set, fix $x\in X$, and let $Y:=X\setminus\{x\}.$ Now let $\mathcal T$ be the set of all subsets $U$ of $X$ such that either (1) $U\subseteq Y$ or (2) $x\in U$ and $X\setminus U$ is finite.
Then $\mathcal T$ is a compact Hausdorff topology on $X.$ In particular, if $X$ is infinite, then $\langle X,\mathcal T\rangle$ is homeomorphic to the Alexandrov one-point compactification of $Y$ in the discrete topology; if $X$ is finite, then $\mathcal T$ is discrete.

Comment: +1. Thanks very much for this observation.

Comment: No problem at all. I had this realization while I was learning about Alexandrov compactifications, and I'm pleased that my musings came to some use.

Answer (score 13):

Most of this is classical, starting with the memoir by Alexandrov and Urysohn, in which they introduced their notion of the compact Hausdorff space (as *bicompact*), and also of the absolutely closed space (closed in any Hausdorff superspace) including an extensive discussion of them. This and the minimal Hausdorff spaces, and the related stuff, is very nicely presented as exercises in the Bourbaki General Topology; also Engelking covers these topics in his classical monography (which had several editions). Needless to say, a number of research papers was devoted to minimal Hausdorff spaces and similar.

It's easy to see why the standard Euclidean topology in the space of rational numbers cannot be weakened to a compact topology. The key is: Baire property.

A pretty general result of this type appeared in my paper, *Minimal Hausdorff Spaces and $T_1$-Bicompacta*, Soviet DAN 1968, v.178, pp 24-26. Let's talk about $T_1$-spaces only, so that *complete regularity* implies *Hausdorff*. **Theorem 1'** states:

Let a completely regular space be a countable union of its nowhere dense (i.e. having empty interior) compact subsets. Then its topology does not dominate any minimal Hausdorff topology.

Still more general (but easier to prove) is **Theorem 1** there:

Let a Hausdorff space   $X$ be a countable union of its nowhere dense (i.e. closed and having empty interior) compact subsets. Assume also that it is a dense subspace of a Hausdorff space which has the Baire property. Then topology of   $X$   does not dominate any minimal Hausdorff topology.

The formulation of Theorem 1 suggests how to prove Theorem 1'.

***NOTE:***   in the published paper the formulation of Theorem 1' missed word **countable** (it appears in Theorem 1).

Comment: I didn't state any results about the relation between $T_1$- and $T_2$-compacta to keep my answer reasonably short. One can find some results and references in the paper mentioned above.

Answer (score 8):

In fact there are spaces which are "minimal Hausdorff" -- they have no coarser Hausdorff topology -- but are not compact. It turns out that these spaces are "H-closed" (every open cover has a finite subfamily whose *closures* cover) and semi-regular (the collection of regular open sets form a base). A minimal Hausdorff space is compact exactly when it is Urysohn. Spaces which have coarser minimal Hausdorff topologies are called Katĕtov. A "nice" example of a space which is not Katĕtov is the space of rational numbers $\mathbb{Q}$.

I'm not sure about compact spaces, but I *suspect* that a Hausdorff space has a unique coarser minimal Hausdorff topology exactly when it is H-closed. One direction I'm sure of -- the semi-regularization of an H-closed space is minimal Hausdorff.

By the way, (one of) THE BOOK(s) on this topic is *Extensions and absolutes of Hausdorff spaces* by Porter and Woods, however it discusses Hausdorff spaces almost exclusively.

Answer (score 8):

*"Under what circumstances does a Hausdorff topology [properly] refine a unique compact Hausdorff topology?"*

If $X$ is locally compact (non-compact, Hausdorff), then $X$ refines infinitely many distinct compact Hausdorff topologies. However, there are also examples of (non-compact, Hausdorff) spaces $X$ that refine a unique compact Hausdorff topology.

**Theorem:** If $X$ is a non-compact, locally compact Hausdorff topology that refines at least one compact Hausdorff topology, then it refines at least $|X|$ compact Hausdorff topologies.

*Proof:* See the proof of Proposition 4.3 in [this paper](https://wrbrian.files.wordpress.com/2012/01/refinements1.pdf). The basic idea is to take a one-point compactification of $X$, then take the point at infinity and glue it back down onto any point of $X$. Now you have a topology that's compact, Hausdorff, and refined by $X$. Choosing different targets for the gluing will result in different topologies. QED. [Note: These topologies, while different, may be homeomorphic, for example if $X$ is the real line.]

In contrast, we have the following example. Let $I = [0,1]$ (the set, not the topological space). Let $\sigma$ denote the usual topology on $I$, and let $\langle \sigma,A \rangle$ denote the topology on $I$ with subbasis $\sigma \cup \{A\}$. Let $A = I \setminus \{\frac{1}{n}:n \geq 1\}$. Then I claim that $\sigma$ is the only compact Hausdorff topology refined by $\langle \sigma,A \rangle$.

Let $\tau$ be any compact Hausdorff topology that is refined by $\langle \sigma,A \rangle$.

Notice that if $a > 0$ then $\sigma$ and $\langle \sigma,A \rangle$ agree on $[a,1]$. Furthermore, since $[a,1]$ is compact Hausdorff, passing to $\tau$ will not change its topology, since any strictly coarser topology on $[a,1]$ fails to be Hausdorff. Thus $\sigma$ and $\tau$ agree on every $[a,1]$, and hence on $(0,1]$.

Thus $\tau$ is a (Hausdorff) one-point compactification of $(0,1]$ (with the usual topology). But there's only one of those! So $\langle \sigma,A \rangle$ is refined by only one compact Hausdorff topology, namely $\sigma$.